# Calculate balance / running total from within an array

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I have an array with items where one of the entries is another array which contains line items

The line items have Date QtyIn QtyOut

Hard to draw the table for, but something like this:

| itemID | ItemName | Stock | LineItems |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  |  |  | Date, QtyIn, QtyOut |
| AppG1 | Green Apple | 100 | 2021-02-01, 100, 0 |
|  |  |  | 2021-02-02, 0, 60 |
|  |  |  | 2021-02-03, 0, 10 |
| AppR1 | Red Apple | 85 | 2021-02-01, 500, 0 |
|  |  |  | 2021-02-02, 10, 0 |

I would like to generate a **running balance** for each line item where this is the Stock +QtyIn -QtyOut for each entry

| itemID | ItemName | Stock | LineItems |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  |  |  | Date, QtyIn, QtyOut, **Balance** |
| AppG1 | Green Apple | 100 | 2021-02-01, 100, 0, **200** |
|  |  |  | 2021-02-02 0 60, **140** |
|  |  |  | 2021-02-03 0 10, **130** |
| AppR1 | Red Apple | 85 | 2021-02-01, 500, 0, **585** |
|  |  |  | 2021-02-02, 10, 0, **595** |

Again, hard to draw the table but hopefully you see what I mean

My code looks something like this:

```
var lineItems = from li in lineitems
                select new LineItem
                {ItemID = li.ItemID,
                 QtyIn = li.QtyIn,
                 QtyOut = li.QtyOut,
                 DueDate = li.DueDate,
                }).OrderBy(o => o.ItemID).ThenBy(c => c.DueDate);

var result = from i in headeritems
             select new HeaderItem
             {ItemID = i.ItemID,
              ItemName= i.ItemName,
              Stock = i.ItemStock,
              LineItems = lineItems.Where(w => w.ItemID == i.ItemID)
             };

return result;
```

I was hoping I could just add a line to the LineItem class that calculated the balance, but I can't work out how to iterate the lineitems. I then thought I could add it where the lineitems are added to the result array but again, I can't see how to do this. Is there a way I can do it without having to go through the whole table using a loop?

Comment: Trying to understand: why is line 2 and 3 of expected result both 200? Shouldn't they 140 and 130 resp.?

Comment: You are right, typo sorry. Edited question

Answer (score 1):

You can use an extra variable which you close over in the lambda, to aggregate the balance.

We use `let balance` because we must reset on every `HeaderItem`, furthermore, we must use `ToList()` to ensure the calculation is actually reset correctly.

```cs
var result = from i in headeritems
             let balance = i.Stock
             select new HeaderItem
             {ItemID = i.ItemID,
              ItemName= i.ItemName,
              Stock = i.ItemStock,
              LineItems = lineItems
                 .Where(w => w.ItemID == i.ItemID)
                 .Select(li => {
                      li.Balance = balance += li.QtyIn - li.QtyOut;
                      return li;
                 })
                 .ToList()
              };
```